# Has the memory leaked?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

```
void foo(int i)
{
    char* p = new char[10];
    
    if (i) 
    {
        p = 0;
    }
    
    delete[] p;
}
```

In the above code snippet, `p` resource was referenced to zero. Will this create a memory leak in my code?

Comment: Yes, it will leak.

Comment: @mohammed_thoyyib_tk To free the memory you allocated with `new[]`, you must pass the value you got from `new[]` to `delete[]`. How can you do that if you replace it with zero?

Comment: Compile your C++ code with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` then use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) on your executable file

Answer (score 1):

Yes it leaks in case i != 0.
Your variable `p` points to some address in memory and by doing `p = 0;` you erase that pointer. So the instruction `delete[] p;` will work for a `nullptr` pointer and you'll not free the allocated memory.

For this type of problems we use smart pointers (unique_ptr, shared_ptr, ...) and STL containers and objects like `std::string`, `std::vector<char>`, `std::list<char>` and so on.

So, in your case you have to change code to something like that

```
{
    char* p = new char[10];
    
    if (i) 
    {
        if (p) {
            delete[] p;
            p = 0;
        }
    }
    
    if (p) {
        delete[] p;
        p = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your function `foo`, you are setting the value of the pointer `p`, which actually is a pointer to the beginning of your dynamic array, to 0 if `i` is non-zero:

```
if(i) 
{
    p = 0;
}
```

Therefore, when `i` is non-zero, `p` no longer points to the start of your array and the `delete` command will fail to deallocate the array that you create inside the function.

So yes, when `i` is non-zero, your function will leak memory. I wouldn't change `p` if I were you. Keep that unchanged until the end so that you call `delete []` on it and deallocate the array.

---

Alternatively, consider using a `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector<char> vec(10);
```

This does something equivalent except it will take care of the memory allocation/deallocation for you automatically.